# Java - Run a batch file and Notify when done, keeping CMD window open

Tags: java, batch-file, command-line, cmd, command

I am trying to create a java program that executes a batch file and then does some code after.
My program executes the batch file perfectly but notifies me when the cmd is launched because the main thread is done.
However, I need to keep the ***cmd window open***.
I tried using a processBuilder with .redirectErrorStream(true), but it does not display the cmd text in the window, only in the java console.
Thank you in advance for your help.
Here is my code:

```
    String cmd = "temp.bat";
    String path = "E:\\USMT\\";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + path + cmd);
    int exitVal = p.waitFor();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done", "Confirmation", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `pause` at the end of the batch file. This should keep the cmd window from closing yet allow `p.waitFor()` to return.